# I've been a teacher

Tags: grammar

I was a teacher. I am not now. Does the following sentence convey this idea?

> I've been a teacher.

Comment: It sounds odd on its own, but it would be OK in the context of someone summarising the jobs they have had in their lifetime - "I've been a musician, a teacher and now I'm a writer."

Comment: Hello Stephen, The question is simpler now, but it's still a request for proof reading, which is off-topic for this site. If you have a question about a specific point of grammar, please explain what aspect you're confused about -- I'm guessing *present perfect for past events with present outcomes*, but I shouldn't have to guess. Also, at ELL, we expect people asking questions to have done some basic research themselves, and to explain what they already know and why their question is still not answered.

Comment: Sometimes I have an idea to express in English. I don't know how to express it correctly. I might make up a sentence, and then ask here whether it can express my idea. I have no idea why this kind of questions is unacceptable. Anyway, thank you for your reminding.